# Filling 3d array using for loop in C programming

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I'm working on my class project and I'm currently stuck at the most basic one. Basically I have to fill the stack of boxes using loops and 3d array. The stack is 4 width, 4 length and 3 height and I have to fill boxes with 100 items each.

```
void main(){
    int boxShleve[3][4][4];
    int i, j, k;
    for (i=0; i<3; ++i){
        for (j=0; j<4; ++j){
            for (k=0; k<4; ++k){
                boxShleve[3][4][4] = 100;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d", boxShleve[3][4][4]);
}
```

This is the broken piece of my work... How do I make each array has 100 element in it?

Comment: You never use the index variables `i`, `j` or `k` as indexes in the array. Instead you have the size as index, and as you (should) know arrays are indexed from zero to size minus one, so those indexes are all out of bounds.

Comment: consider what happens when you fill an array `int box[4];` initialize them properly and then `printf("%d", box[4]);` when you have 0 indexing.

Comment: `printf("%d", boxShleve[3][4][4]);` --> `printf("%d", boxShleve[2][3][3]);`

Answer (score 3):

This is what you meant to do:

```
int main()
{
    int boxShleve[3][4][4];
    int i, j, k;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        for (j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
            for (k = 0; k < 4; ++k)
                boxShleve[i][j][k] = 100;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            for (k = 0; k < 4; k++)
                printf("%d ", boxShleve[i][j][k]);

    return 0;
}
```

The reason you need the nested loops is to use the `i`, `j` and `k` as indexes to access the array. So you have to use them.

Same for printing the values.

Answer (score 0):

A faster way to do this if you are using GCC is as follows.

```
int boxShleve[3][4][4] = {
    {[0 ... 2] = 100 },
    {[0 ... 3] = 100 },
    {[0 ... 3] = 100 } };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int boxShleve[3][4][4];
    size_t size = sizeof(boxShleve)/sizeof(int);
    int *p = &boxShleve[0][0][0];
    while(size--)
        *p++ = 100;
    printf("%d\n", boxShleve[2][3][3]);//last element,
    return 0;
}
```